# Electron react listen to stdout from a terminal command

Tags: javascript, events, electron, node-streams

I am writing an electron app that needs to execute a long-running process from the command line and monitor the output in real-time, but I am not sure how to achieve this goal.

Basically if the terminal command prints "Find me!" then I want the app to handle it like some kind of event.

So far I have been able to do:

1. start the terminal command from electron with "spawn"
2. print the output of the terminal command with "console.log"
3. it seems that it keeps printing asynchronously - which is unexpected but good.

tsx: the following code would print the output of the terminal command

```
import { ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams } from 'child_process';

const sendOutput = (output: ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams | string) =>
{
  if (typeof output === 'string') {
      console.log(`${output}\n`);
  } else {
    output.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`${data.toString()}\n`);
    });
    output.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`${data.toString()}\n`);
    });
}
}

export function helloWorldRepeat(){

  let dir = "/Users/les/projects/github/tutorial/les-app/cpp_program";
  let cmd = "helloWorldRepeat"

  let comm = dir+ "/"+cmd;
  let params = [""];

  return {
    command: `command: ${comm} ${params}`,
    process: spawn(comm, params)
  }

export function main(){
  let c = helloWorldRepeat();
  sendOutput(c.process);
}

}
```

Thank you

Comment: I think we don't need to see your C++ code, and this question should not be tagged C++ because it concerns interactions between Electron and the shell, not C++ and the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `child_process.spawn` to run the command, and you'll be listening for signals from `stdout` and `stderr`, which are readable streams. When a signal arrives, that's when your app should act.

```js
let subprocess = child_process.spawn(
    'command', // see note
    ['arg1', 'arg2']
)

subprocess.on('error', () => subprocess = null) // couldn't launch the process
subprocess.stdout.on('data', YOUR_EVENT_HANDLER)
subprocess.stderr.on('data', YOUR_EVENT_HANDLER)
subprocess.on('close', () => subprocess = null)
```

Where `YOUR_EVENT_HANDLER` is [any function suitable for the "data" event on a readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdout), which I believe means it accepts a single string argument and its return is ignored.

The rest of your Electron app wants to be notified when content arrives -- or, the right content -- but you don't want the rest of your Electron app to have to know anything about child processes or readable streams. So, you should probably put all of this into a function that returns an EventEmitter instance, and then `YOUR_EVENT_HANDLER` would fire a clean event whenever it sees content that it cares about, silently doing nothing the rest of the time.

---

Note: for shell builtins and commands on Node's `PATH`, you *can* get away with just the program name, but I have run into [problems doing that in some contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833891/electron-app-cant-access-files-on-only-one-network-drive), so I recommend always providing the absolute path to the command you wish to run.

(That link also has an example showing how to wrap a command in a Promise that waits for the command to terminate and then resolves with all of stdout or stderr.)